# Why would DOORS DXL tempFileName function return \ on Windows 7 64-bit?

Tags: file-permissions, windows-7-x64, temp, ibm-doors

I have IBM DOORS installed on Windows 7 64-bit.  When I run the DOORS DXL function tempFileName() I get \ instead of something like C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp.  I've googled this problem but don't see anything about the issue.  Anyone have an idea?

Some sample code demonstrating the problem is...

```
string productDetailsFile = tempFileName()
print "productDetailsFile = " productDetailsFile "\n"
if(canOpenFile(productDetailsFile, true))
print "Can write to file\n"
Stream out = write productDetailsFile
out << "Created by " doorsname " at " dateAndTime today ""   
if (null out)
{
    print "Could not create file " productDetailsFile ""
    halt
}
flush out
close out
string directory = getDirOf (productDetailsFile)
print "directory = " directory "\n"
string newFileName = directory NLS_("\\") NLS_("DOORS_") doorsInfo(infoVersion) (NLS_(".xml_new"))
print "newFileName = " newFileName "\nAttempting to rename now\n"
string errorMsg = renameFile(productDetailsFile, newFileName)
if (!null errorMsg)
{
    print "Rename failed with error - " errorMsg "\nTrying with modified file name now\n"
    newFileName = directory NLS_("DOORS_") doorsInfo(infoVersion) (NLS_(".xml_new"))
    print "newFileName = " newFileName "\nAttempting to rename now\n"
    errorMsg = renameFile(productDetailsFile, newFileName)
    if(!null errorMsg)
        print "Still fails. Stopping script now, please send the DXL Output to Support"
 }
 else
     print "Rename successful"
```

Comment: Can you post your code too please. I run `print tempFileName()` on a windows 7 64 bit machine and get the correct response.

Comment: @Steve, yesterday, we found the root cause.  For completeness, I went ahead and posting some sample code which demonstrated the problem.  Thanks for offering to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause was that the computer running DOORs had a "System variable" of TEMP set to
C:\Users\user-name\AppData\Local\Temp and there were no "User variables" set
for TEMP.

To get the function working:

1. The "System variable" for TEMP was changed to "%SystemRoot%\TEMP"
2. Created another "System variable" called "TMP" and set it to "%SystemRoot%\TEMP" as well.
3. Created 2 "User variables": TEMP and TMP and set those to "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp".